# Why does the top bar nag me to review close votes occasionally?

Tags: discussion, top-bar

I get a little red dot on the top bar and when I click on it I see another red dot for "review close votes".

How/when/why does this nag me to do so? What's the deal with this?

Comment: I think the red dot comes up when there are more than 200 items in the queue, and a yellow dot when there are more than 100.  This is new to the revised nav bar, so there may be changes going on.

Comment: @hardmath I sometimes get a red dot when there's only a single item in the low quality posts que although that might be because it gets resolved quickly

Comment: I've seen it occasionally, the red dot.  But it doesn't say anything to me; I don't hear anything generated by the red dot, i.e., it doesn't "nag" me.  I've been a wee bit distracted by the red dot, in the sense that I haven't yet "acclimated" to the appearance of the red dot, just as I acclimated to the square box on the top nav bar listing the number of reviews in the queues.  It's just a matter of time until  the distraction of the stimulus (red dot) in your vision field on MSE is extinguished.

Comment: I have never seen that red dot. Though come to think of it, I hadn't bothered to check where they moved the review link to, until now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment this is to draw your attention to the fact that there are relatively many pending review tasks.

Thus, if you see it and are willing to help out click on it to visit one of the review queues.

The details of what relatively many means are explained in this answer: [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly)

This site is in the  "large" site category. Briefly, for each queue there is a threshold and if one is above it the global indicator appears (for close votes it's 200 for a red dot, and for the others it's 10 (reopen, edits), 20 (LQ), or 30 (LA, FP)).  A gray dot just means there is an item.

Note that the feature itself that the top-bar nags you when there are many items in the queues is not new to the redesigned top-bar. In the old one there appeared an orange box with the rough number of items to be reviewed written in it.